# Entity Framework class in ItemType not showing fields in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, repeater, strong-typing

I am using **Entity Framwework 6**
I have a table named `Action` which I want it to be bound to a repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpAction" runat="server" ItemType="Action">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <%# Item.ActionID %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the code-behind:

```
 var context = new FPSDB_newEntities();    
 rpAction.DataSource = (from a in context.Actions select a).ToList();
 rpAction.DataBind();
```

Now it is giving be a compile time error:

> Action does not contain a definition of ActionID

Although, `ActionID` is one of the fields in Action Table

When I browse the field, it shows some methods but not the fields of the `Action` table as shown below.

[image]

Also here is the image where one can see the table definition
[image]
The same code is running fine for other tables in my SQL server Database. 
Can anyone solve this problem 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to a conflict between the type of your table `Action` and the .Net type `Action<T>`.

You can see it because Intellisense suggests you all methods available for `Action<T>`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx

The thing, you can do is to rename your table (Code-First) or to rename the the table-type it in the EDMX (Database-First)

**EDIT:** Another solution is to use the fully qualified type name of your table `Action` to avoid the name conflict, like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpAction" runat="server" ItemType="MyNamespace.Action">
```

Comment: But I dont have the namespace since I have a website not a project

Comment: Your class `Action` does have a `namespace`. It's a basic concept in `C#`. Open the class file and take a look to his `namespace`.

Comment: I hope you can suggest me how to add namespace. Is it necessary even if it is a website

Comment: Since it's an autogenerated class from EDMX, What is the namespace of your context ? It is not a subject of "necessary even if it is a website", it's a subject of "namespaces are a basic thing of C# classes". Also a website in .Net is not simply a website, it's an "application running in a web context". So all you can "have" in an applcaition (console, WPF, ...) you can "have" it in a ASP.Net app.

Comment: i fetch the data as below:           var context = new FPSDB_newEntities();    
 rpAction.DataSource = (from a in context.Actions select a).ToList();
 rpAction.DataBind();                                                                          
FPSDB_newEntities class is here :                                                            public partial class FPSDB_newEntities : DbContext
{
    public FPSDB_newEntities()
        : base("name=FPSDB_newEntities")
    {
    }and I found the name space here in the class of DBConext: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AmkHNLSXkVWOgbES2-ns4ylGSc_JdQ

Comment: `System.Data.Entity` is the namespace for `DbContext` not the one for `FPSDB_newEntities`. If there is nothing in the generated code by EntityFramework, It takes the namespace specified in the project properties under "default namespace" (next to the "assembly name").

Comment: The namespace found is System.Data.Entity. System.Data.Entity.Action does not work. In order to avoid renaming a table name I think I should convert the website project to a web application project using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx, what do you suggest?

Comment: Read my previous comment. The answer is in it.